# The application draws all of an image, unscaled - the image is not scaled when the application is finished drawing it - correct?

Tags: grammar

> The sprite sheet application uses drawImage() in the simplest possible way: The application draws all of an image, **unscaled**, that is stored in an Image object, into the application’s canvas. In **the Chapter 4** and throughout the rest of this book, you will see more advanced uses for drawImage().

1. Is the adjective **unscaled** in the second sentence used in an adverbial sense? So, as I understand this, it tells the reader that when the application is done drawing an image (all of it - the entire image), the image is not going to be scaled. Is that right?
2. Also I have a question about the usage of the article **the** which is placed in front of the words **Chapter 4**. Don't you think this is incorrect? As far as I know, generally you don't use articles when talking about entities that have a numeral attached to them. Am I right?

Comment: You are correct about that article. Looks like an editing error to me (perhaps it used to say “the next chapter” and then it was changed to “Chapter 4” without removing the article, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The sprite sheet application uses drawImage() in the simplest possible way: The application draws all of an image, unscaled, that is stored in an Image object, into the application’s canvas.

I could be wrong, but I think *unscaled* is acting as an adjective that is modifying *image*. In any case, you are right that when the image is drawn, it will be unscaled.

You know, they often make computer books as fat as possible on purpose. (752 pages for this one!) The books sell better that way. People think that a fat book represents better value for money when they see it on a store shelf. But that doesn't always make for concise writing. I think that sentence could be simplified a lot:

> The sprite sheet application uses drawImage() in the simplest possible way: It draws an Image object, entire and unscaled, into the application’s canvas.

Comment: Just as a comment, while "entire and" is excellent for clarity, it could be omitted as well without leading to confusion for most native English speakers.

Comment: @Anaksunaman, it seems that with `drawImage()`, you can clip out and use just a part of the source image. That's what the author meant by "draws all of an image".

Comment: @user1473511, this is the full method: `drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height)`. `sx`, `sy`, `swidth`, and `sheight` are optional parameters that specify the clipping rectangle. The author was saying that he was not using these clipping parameters.

Comment: My comment IS incorrect. While using the function in its simplest form would not utilize the clipping feature, I incorrectly imply that one cannot clip an image as part of the HTML5 Canvas/Javascript drawImage() function.

I agreed with Anaksunaman because the original text did not choose to clarify that clipping was possible, because it was called in its simplest form, and was speaking to the subject of scaling. I've deleted my erroneous comment.

Comment: @Dangph Hmm. Indeed this seems to be the case. For clarity, it cannot be omitted. An alternate phrasing might also be "It draws an image object, unclipped and unscaled, into the application's canvas." then?

Comment: @Anaksunaman, yes, _unclipped_ would be better. I like how it parallels _unscaled_.